# Missing Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When I create new project in visual studio 2010 I don't see Windows Forms Application template for c#. I see only template for WPF, Windows Service and class library.
Any suggestion what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close all instance of Visual Studio. Open visual studio command prompt and type,

```
devenv /installvstemplates
```

Read more

1. [Missing templates in Visual Studio installed templates](http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/05/06/missing-templates-in-visual-studio-installed-templates/)
2. [What to do when Visual Studio templates are missing](http://blog.dileno.com/archive/201009/what-to-do-when-visual-studio-templates-are-missing/)